# Show searchview in actionbar only in parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, searchview

I am wondering how to show searchview in actionbar only in parent fragment. For now, when I submit a search from searchview in actionbar and go to next fragment, I still can see the searchview in my child fragment. Any suggestions to fix that? Thanks.

For now, in my parent class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.homesearchbar, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("HomeToSearch_keyword", query);
            SearchVC searchVC = new SearchVC();
            searchVC.setArguments(bundle);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.HomeVC_frameChildFragment, searchVC)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

homesearchbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title=""
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Did you try to override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` in your child fragment and then call `menu.findItem(R.id.search).setVisible(false);`  or whatever your id is and set in `onCreate` method `setHasOptionsMenu(true):`

Comment: Just try to override ```onPrepareOptionsMenu``` and then call ```menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);``` but everything still remain the same. What do you mean of set in ```onCreate``` method ```setHasOptionsMenu(true);```? Do you mean put it on child fragment?

Comment: Yes I meant to do all that in child fragment

Comment: You are right. You can post it as solution. I can vote it. For child fragments I don't want to show searchView, I ```@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItem m = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        if (m != null)
            m.setVisible(false);
    }``` and ```@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }``` 
For child fragments I want to show, just change m.setVisible(false); to m.setVisible(true);

Comment: Okay great I'm glad it solves your issue I will post a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide `searchView` inside child fragment `override` inside it `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method. Then inside that method you can do something like this: `menu.findItem(R.id.search).setVisible(false);` or eventually when needed you can change it to `true`. And also don't forget to `override onCreate` method where you will put `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`